# AWS Step Functions - pass list into Glue's argument

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

Within my workflow I query DynamoDB for tables whose `load_fail` status equals `1`.

If there is at least one table, Glue job needs to start with that list of tables as `--source_tables` argument.

Below is my entire state machine.

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Query",
  "States": {
    "Query": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Choice",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "source_tables_load_status",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "load_fail = :load_fail",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
          ":load_fail": {
            "S": "1"
          }
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:dynamodb:query",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "count.$": "$.Count",
        "startTime.$": "$$.Execution.StartTime",
        "items.$": "$.Items[*].table_name.S"
      }
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.count",
          "NumericGreaterThanEquals": 1,
          "Next": "start_glue"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Success"
    },
    "start_glue": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "data-moving-glue",
        "Arguments": {
          "--dynamodb_metadata_table": "metadata_table",
          "--source_tables.$": "$.items"
        }
      },
      "End": true
    },
    "Success": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I'm getting an error caused by `"--source_tables.$": "$.items"`.

Question is how to make `"--source_tables":["dbo.Table_Two", "dbo.Table_Three"]` working by state machine:

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'start_glue' (entered at the event id #9). 
The Parameters '{"JobName":"data-moving-glue","Arguments":{"--dynamodb_metadata_table":"metadata_table","--source_tables":["dbo.Table_Two", "dbo.Table_Three"]}}' 
could not be used to start the Task: [The value for the field '--source_tables' must be a STRING]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I closed the result in quotes making it into a string using `States.Format`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html

```
"--source_tables.$": "States.Format('{}', $.items)"
```

New output is:

```
"--source_tables": "[\"dbo.TableOne\",\"dbo.TableTwo\"]"
```

This on the other hand can be handled with a function.

**`eval` is used only as an example! Don't use it as it can compromise your code!**

```
lst = "[\"dbo.TableOne\",\"dbo.TableTwo\"]"

for t in (eval(lst)): 
    print(t)
```